# How can I use <a> tag in Betheme?

Tags: html, css, web, atag

I would be thankful if you help me. I'm developing a website using Betheme and I wanna use "a" tag in main menu. The href in the tag should be linked to another part in the home page. please see the example:

```
About US| <a href="#product">products</a>| contact US
.
.
.
.
<p id="product">Our Products:
here is the text.</p>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. We need more details about your problem .. Could you please share the sample code?

Comment: Yes not clear question same thought as previous comment. Would be good to add an example of code, output expected or any details related. Like this is somehow difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

of course, I found the solution at the end :). I leave the answer here for those who may have such problem:
On your Betheme platform first go to the section you wanna link it to the main menu. Click edit and on Custom | ID write your ID. Then on your Betheme go to Appearance==> Menu and then create a custom link. For URL you need to set your website+your ID using "#" (e.g. [www.abcd.com/#ID](http://www.abcd.com/#ID)). In addition you need to set a link text to be appeared in the menu.